# Sorting array of objects using the underscore sortBy method

Tags: underscore.js, sorting

I have an array of objects and I want to sort ASC that array by the value of 'home'. That field is always numeric. So I've tried this:

```
_.sortBy(data.home.en, function(obj){ return obj.home });
```

That is working well when value of 'home' is lower then 10, but for some reason 10 goes just after the 1, so my final order looks like this 1,10,11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 . Why is this happening? Thanks...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your `obj.home` values are strings so they're being compared as strings and `'1' < '10'` is true. If you want to sort them like numbers then convert them to numbers:

```
_.sortBy(data.home.en, function(obj){ return +obj.home });
```

or:

```
_.sortBy(data.home.en, function(obj){ return parseInt(obj.home, 10) });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/DpfgV/1/

Comment: return parseInt(obj.home, 10) ==> you can do return `obj.home*1` and will make the trick without using parseInt

Comment: @ncubica: I think `+obj.home` is the more common shortcut.

Comment: but `+obj.home` will add string not numbers so as example if you have `10 (int) + "00" (str)` result its gonna be `1000` but if you write `10 + ("00"*1)` the result will be 10. which its what are you expecting right?

Comment: None of those apply here, we're just doing things like `return +'10'`. You're also dropping a `+`, the "unary plus to cast to number" version of `10 + '00'*1` would be `10 + +'00'` (which requires you to be careful with your whitespace); in cases like this I'd use `parseInt` to make the intent crystal clear.

Comment: Can't understand what the matter is about parseInt: it is clearer for readers, so why should I complicate my code using a shortcut, to save a couple of bits?

Comment: @Tilt: I don't know what the problem is either. If `parseInt` is too hard to type then maybe they're in the wrong profession. Or maybe they just want to appear to be clever. I don't know, I'm too old for all that :)